# Biblatex - End Occurred when \iftrue on line n was incomplete

Tags: biblatex, warnings

I've been trying to troubleshoot this warning I've been getting:

```
(\end occurred when \iftrue on line n was incomplete)
```

where *n* is always the line containing `\begin{document}`, and I've ripped everything out to a few simple lines that still produces the warning:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{main.bib}

\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}
    Nothing important. %\cite{somebibkey}
    %\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The two commented out commands make no difference w/r/t the warning -- uncommenting them has no effect.

There is a single, well-formatted entry in the bib file.  Commenting out the `\bibliography` command makes no difference either.

If I add `\tracingifs=1`, I get a bunch of lines that don't seem particularly helpful (to me):

```
...
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
 ("C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg"
File: biblatex.cfg 
)))
vertical mode: \ifcsname: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifcsname (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\ifx: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\else: \ifx (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifx (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\ifcsname: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifcsname (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\ifx: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\else: \ifx (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifx (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\ifx: (level 1) entered on line 10}
...
{\else: \ifx (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifx (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\ifcsname: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\else: \ifcsname (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifcsname (level 1) entered on line 10}
{restricted horizontal mode: \ifcsname: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\else: \ifcsname (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifcsname (level 1) entered on line 10}
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
{\ifeof: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\else: \ifeof (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifeof (level 1) entered on line 10}
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
{\ifx: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\else: \ifx (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifx (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\ifdefined: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\ifx: (level 2) entered on line 10}
{\else: \ifx (level 2) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifx (level 2) entered on line 10}
{\else: \ifdefined (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifdefined (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\ifdefined: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\ifx: (level 2) entered on line 10}
{\else: \ifx (level 2) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifx (level 2) entered on line 10}
{\else: \ifdefined (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifdefined (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\ifdefined: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\ifx: (level 2) entered on line 10}
{\else: \ifx (level 2) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifx (level 2) entered on line 10}
{\else: \ifdefined (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifdefined (level 1) entered on line 10}
 ("C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx"
{\ifnum: (level 1) entered on line 1}
{\ifnum: (level 2) entered on line 1}
...
{\fi: \iffalse (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\ifeof: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\else: \ifeof (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifeof (level 1) entered on line 10}
 (C:/Users/user/workspaces/tex/luatex-hello-world/src/./_main.aux)
{\iftrue: (level 1) entered on line 10}

\openout1 = _main.aux
{\fi: \iftrue (level 1) entered on line 10}
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 10.
{\ifx: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\fi: \ifx (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\ifx: (level 1) entered on line 10}
```

(The log is 11,619 lines long with `\iftracing=1` -- otherwise I wouldn't have truncated it at what might seem like at random.)

**Note: in the case of the above log, *n* == 10 == where `\begin{document}` was.

This warning appears regardless of whether I'm using LuaLaTeX or pdfTeX.

Versions:

- BibTeX - Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
- biblatex 2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
- LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (MiKTeX 2.9) (rev 5238)
- pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9)

If this just a warning I need to live with, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say here: this looks like a bug report rather than a question (it's clearly a bug in `biblatex`). That said: the development code for the package is currently being adapted to work very differently for BibTeX 'fallback' support, and the issue is not seen by with that, so 'wait for an update' seems the be best to be said.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Joseph Wright commented, that it is best to just wait for the next update of `biblatex`.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I wasn't trying to use the site in lieu of a submitting a bug report, I'm just not familiar enough with biblatex (or latex in general) to have made that call.  It just as easily (if not more likely) that I was the one messing up, not the package.  I can't delete my own questions on here like I can on SO, so do what you must :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-closed conditional is an issue; your input is fine so it's a bug in `biblatex` (or more specifically the BibTeX-support part). At present (April 2016) work is in an advanced stage for altering how the Biber/BibTeX split is handled and with the development version I don't see the problem. I'd therefore suggest 'wait for the maintenance team to update `biblatex`' as the best solution: probably going to happen late-May/early-June 2016.